# Can I limit who can view a .js file while allowing my webpages to view whats contained within?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

The question may seem vague, so i'll state what I want to do in my project and how i'm going about it.

I create estimating workbooks in excel that operate like fully executable programs with a GUI using VBA. The workbooks themselves are used to estimate specific projects. For example, I've created workbooks for estimating basement developments, kitchen renovations, bathroom renovations and other residential renovation projects.

The back end sheets contain the formulas for estimating different tasks and trade/material pricing. In the back end of these workbooks is the mark-up and margin values. The great thing about it, is I can lock the access to the sensitive information so that only select few people can view or modify the values. The front end of the workbook allows the estimators that work for the companies I build these for, limited access. It also reduces the amount of errors an estimator can make.

At this point, i'm building a web app using Javascript/jquery to increase my client base. With the excel workbooks, only those using excel can work with the workbooks due to, as I understand, excel being the only program that can run VBA macros.

**The Problem:**

Due to my limited knowledge of PHP and SQL, I havent set up a database to store and PHP files to retrieve information.

To get around this, I'd like to store all of my global variables in a separate .js sheet, inaccessible from the developer tools on any browser. This way I can hide from my clients competitors and clients the information on profit margins and individual costs of their projects. A separate sheet would also make it easier to update values. I would also like to hide the general structure and framework so that it can't be easily imitated or copied.

Maybe there is another solution to what I'm looking for?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You can use a Javascript obfuscator to make it harder to read the script. E.g. http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Thanks, checked it out. I started learning php and mySQL for the ultimate solution. hopefully the learning curve is short :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you need some information to show a webpage and don't have any server-side code, the information must be in the user's browser.

On the other hand, I never tried writing or hacking VBA so I don't know how hard that is, but conceptually it simply can't be different: if you compute something on untrusted client's computer, the data used in the computation is not secure.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the reply!